# duplicate symbol _fopen_file_func on C code, in objective-c project

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode4, static-libraries, compiler-optimization

In my IOS project i'm use multiple statics frameworks than use minizip in her code.

when i compile i have an error for a duplicate symbol.

if this error is due to a class, it's really simple (rename class, repair the error )

But in my case, the duplicate symbole provide from the "minizip" files ( like ioapi.c, zip.c unzip.c ) they are load in the frameworks.

How can it's possible to work correctly in this case ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is the downside of Objective-C's single name-space.

If you can get an any of the header files, remove or rename them.
If you cannot get at them, you'll need to get the sources and rename/rebuid them, or use another library.

Comment: i have the headers and C files for minizip. But i don't think a simple rename is best way, because inside the ioapi.c file, all function aren't on class.

Answer (score 0):

@Pixman: Look closely at the files you have (most recently) imported into your project.

I found a situation where two versions of the same files (i.e., `ioapi.c`, `ioapi.h`, `mztools.c`, `mztools.h`, `unzip.c`, `unzip.h`, `zip.c`, `zip.h`) were integrated into the project (at different levels) - therefore producing duplicate symbols.

These duplicated files already existed (in support of another file decompression need) so I **removed the second copy** of these files from the project, and the problem with duplicate symbols went away (as you would expect).

One way to see if duplicate file (and likely symbol) names exist in your project is to look at the **Compiled Sources** option available under the **Build Phases** portion of the project.
The added value with this view is that the path to each file is visible, and you can use this to figure out which (of the duplicate) files you want to remove.